# How to filter dataframe by dates in a column stored in variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, dplyr, data-science

I'm writing an R function that has to take input data, which has any kinf of column with dates in it.
And so based on this column I have to then filter this whole data so that it would return data between specific dates.

The problem is that in theory I can't look at this data and what is the name of the column that stores this date, so I first find this column and I can store in some variable.

Then I can't really do anything, because filter from dplyr doesn't want to work unless I give a specific name of the column in the form of character and not a variable. None of other methods I tried seem to be working.

(date_check is a condition to check if dates exist and have proper form and it works perfectly)

```
cols <- colnames(select_if(input.data, date_check == TRUE))
names(input.data)[names(input.data) == cols] <- dates.column.name

date_check <- sapply(input.data, function(x) !all(is.na(as.Date(as.character(x),format="%Y-%m-%d"))))
```

The part of the function looks like this and it works great if the user doesn't give an argument and it's set to default. But the condition that works for this default value doesn't want to work later if the column name is specified by the user.

```
modifier <- function(input.data, dates.column.name = "Date") {
  date_check <- sapply(input.data, function(x) !all(is.na(as.Date(as.character(x),format="%Y-%m-%d"))))
  if (missing(dates.column.name)) {
    cols <- colnames(select_if(input.data, date_check == TRUE))
    names(input.data)[names(input.data) == cols]  <- "Date"
  } else {
    cols <- colnames(select_if(input.data, date_check == TRUE))
    names(input.data)[names(input.data) == cols] <- dates.column.name
  } 
  if (missing(dates.column.name)) {
    input.data$Date <- as.Date(input.data$Date, format= "%Y-%m-%d")
    input.data <- filter(input.data, Date < "2014-12-12" & Date > "2013-01-01")
  } else {
    input.data[, dates.column.name] <- as.Date(input.data[, dates.column.name], format= "%Y-%m-%d")
    input.data <- input.data[(input.data$dates.column.name> "2012-12-03" && input.data$dates.column.name < "2014-12-05"),]
  }
  input.data
}
```

Could someone help me out how can I access this column to be able to filter its dates?

If I pass a small dataframe and give it default second argument it would look something like this.
Original data:

```
 Row.ID        Order.ID  Ship.Date    Ship.Mode
1  32298  CA-2012-124891 2012-07-31     Same Day
2  26341   IN-2013-77878 2013-02-07 Second Class
3  25330   IN-2013-71249 2013-10-18  First Class
4  13524 ES-2013-1579342 2013-01-30  First Class
5  47221    SG-2013-4320 2013-11-06     Same Day
6  22732   IN-2013-42360 2013-07-01 Second Class
```

```
modifier(exam_data)
```

Output:

```
Row.ID        Order.ID       Date    Ship.Mode
1  26341   IN-2013-77878 2013-02-07 Second Class
2  25330   IN-2013-71249 2013-10-18  First Class
3  13524 ES-2013-1579342 2013-01-30  First Class
4  47221    SG-2013-4320 2013-11-06     Same Day
5  22732   IN-2013-42360 2013-07-01 Second Class
```

But if i give it the second argument it looks like this:

```
modifier(exam_data, dates.column.name = "XXX")

 Row.ID Order.ID  XXX Ship.Mode
NA       NA     <NA> <NA>      <NA>
NA.1     NA     <NA> <NA>      <NA>
NA.2     NA     <NA> <NA>      <NA>
NA.3     NA     <NA> <NA>      <NA>
NA.4     NA     <NA> <NA>      <NA>
NA.5     NA     <NA> <NA>      <NA>
```

Comment: `date_check` isn't an arguemnts, it helps to define `cols` variable. After that, it's not used

Comment: when I apply the function on the data, it says `modifier(exam_data)#
Error in is_logical(.predicate) : object 'date_check' not found`  Is the date_check in your global env

Comment: yes, my bad, for it to work you have to add it in the function, i updated again

Comment: I see some issues in your code ``nput.data$dates.column.name` should be `inpput.data[[dates.column.name]]`.  Also, the condition is repeated twice `if (missing(dates.column.name))`.

Comment: I posted a solution.  I have a doubt regarding the passing of a column name that doesn't have in the data or an incorrect column name.  What is the expected behavior for that case?  Do you want to return the whole dataset?

Comment: What is the expected output when you pass a wrong column name or one that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Here, we could convert the column name to symbol with `ensym` (which will also work if the column name is passed unquoted) and evaluate (`!!`)

```
modifier <- function(input.data, dates.column.name = "Date") {
      
    # // convert to a symbol
    # // can also convert unquoted argument to symbol
    datecolumn <- rlang::ensym(dates.column.name)
    if(missing(dates.column.name)) { # // => evaluates if no date argument
       input.data %>%
          # // General : matches substring of column name
          # //         : can apply to more than one column  
           mutate(across(ends_with('Date'),
                  ~ as.Date(., '%Y-%m-%d'))) %>%
          # // General : matches substring of column name
                       : can apply to more than one column
         filter(across(ends_with('Date'), 
               ~ . < "2014-12-12" & . > "2013-01-01"))
      
      } else {
        input.data %>%
            # // evaluates the rhs of assignment operator (:=)
            # // assigns to evaluation of the string converted symbol
            mutate(!! rlang::as_name(datecolumn) :=
                     as.Date(!! datecolumn, '%Y-%m-%d')) %>%
            filter(!! datecolumn > "2012-12-03" & 
                   !! datecolumn < "2014-12-05")
      
      
      }
 

}
```

-testing

```
modifier(exam_data) # // no arguments for dates.column.name, missing => TRUE
  Row.ID        Order.ID  Ship.Date    Ship.Mode
1  26341   IN-2013-77878 2013-02-07 Second Class
2  25330   IN-2013-71249 2013-10-18  First Class
3  13524 ES-2013-1579342 2013-01-30  First Class
4  47221    SG-2013-4320 2013-11-06     Same Day
5  22732   IN-2013-42360 2013-07-01 Second Class

modifier(exam_data, dates.column.name = Ship.Date) # // unquoted dates column  name
  Row.ID        Order.ID  Ship.Date    Ship.Mode
1  26341   IN-2013-77878 2013-02-07 Second Class
2  25330   IN-2013-71249 2013-10-18  First Class
3  13524 ES-2013-1579342 2013-01-30  First Class
4  47221    SG-2013-4320 2013-11-06     Same Day
5  22732   IN-2013-42360 2013-07-01 Second Class
 
modifier(exam_data, dates.column.name = "Ship.Date") # // quoted dates column name
  Row.ID        Order.ID  Ship.Date    Ship.Mode
1  26341   IN-2013-77878 2013-02-07 Second Class
2  25330   IN-2013-71249 2013-10-18  First Class
3  13524 ES-2013-1579342 2013-01-30  First Class
4  47221    SG-2013-4320 2013-11-06     Same Day
5  22732   IN-2013-42360 2013-07-01 Second Class
```

Comment: it still returns a dataframe full of NAs when I pass non-default argument :/

Comment: @Lusieslav I showed 3 cases, and it is testing well for me

Comment: @Lusieslav can you show the argument you are passing and what would be the expected output

Comment: The thing is - I'm storing name of this column as a variable, but this name may vary depending on dataframe. So it won't always be the same and it theory I can't "see" its name, and that's why I'm storing it in some variable.

Comment: @Lusieslav  IN that case, just use `!!` in the `modifier`

Comment: @Lusieslav you can do `coldate <- "Ship.Date";
modifier(exam_data, dates.column.name = !!coldate)`